# Problem with running react native android

Tags: android, react-native

I am having an issue running my react-native android app. I get this error. I am not really sure what I am doing wrong. This is the first time I am running a react native app on android. Been struggling with this for weeks and I am not sure what to do anymore.

```
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
131 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 129 up-to-date
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"base-extension"). Expected elements are <{}codename>,<{}layoutlib>,<{}api-level>
/Users/olasubomiolawepo/Desktop/Connect GCP/android/app/src/main/java/com/connect/MainActivity.java:16: error: illegal start of type
  },
   ^
/Users/olasubomiolawepo/Desktop/Connect GCP/android/app/src/main/java/com/connect/MainActivity.java:16: error: <identifier> expected
  },
    ^
/Users/olasubomiolawepo/Desktop/Connect GCP/android/app/src/main/java/com/connect/MainActivity.java:17: error: illegal start of type
  @Override
  ^
/Users/olasubomiolawepo/Desktop/Connect GCP/android/app/src/main/java/com/connect/MainActivity.java:17: error: ';' expected
  @Override
           ^
4 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

 BUILD FAILED in 26s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"base-extension"). Expected elements are <{}codename>,<{}layoutlib>,<{}api-level>
/Users/olasubomiolawepo/Desktop/Connect GCP/android/app/src/main/java/com/connect/MainActivity.java:16: error: illegal start of type
  },
   ^
/Users/olasubomiolawepo/Desktop/Connect GCP/android/app/src/main/java/com/connect/MainActivity.java:16: error: <identifier> expected
  },
    ^
/Users/olasubomiolawepo/Desktop/Connect GCP/android/app/src/main/java/com/connect/MainActivity.java:17: error: illegal start of type
  @Override
  ^
/Users/olasubomiolawepo/Desktop/Connect GCP/android/app/src/main/java/com/connect/MainActivity.java:17: error: ';' expected
  @Override
           ^
4 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


BUILD FAILED in 26s

    at makeError (/Users/olasubomiolawepo/Desktop/Connect GCP/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at /Users/olasubomiolawepo/Desktop/Connect GCP/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (/Users/olasubomiolawepo/Desktop/Connect GCP/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (/Users/olasubomiolawepo/Desktop/Connect GCP/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:192:9)
```

I have tried updating my ANDROID_HOME, checking my Gradle properties. Yet nothing is working. I have also tried cleaning my Gradle file and properties. All my SDKs are up to date.

Here is my MainActivity.Java file:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code in MainActivity.java? Have you had to edit anything in that file?

Comment: Hey @Abe I just uploaded a snippet of my MainActivity.java file. Thank You

Comment: Your package identifier typically has three parts, like it says in the first error in that trace (i.e. `package com.connect.app`). That could be causing the rest of the file to parse incorrectly. Do you have an android/app directory?

Comment: Yes, I do. Is there a specific code snippet you would like to view

Comment: Try changing line 1 of MainActivity.java to `package com.connect.app`